# how to handle MissingRouteException in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need handle **MissingRouteException** in cakephp3.

I tried to handle exception (in a view file):

```
try {
     $url = Router::url($params);//$params was generated dynamically!
} catch (Exception $exc) {
     $url = Router::url('/');
}
```

but do not worked , and **MissingRouteException** Occur with this error:

```
    Error: A route matching "..." could not be found.
```

Help me please...

Answer (score 0):

The namespace of Exception had problem.

use

```
 } catch (\Exception $exc) {
```

inestead of:

```
 } catch (Exception $exc) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not test it but I think you can create a AppExeptionHandler class.

```
class AppExceptionHandler extends ErrorHandler {

    public static function handleException($errorType) {
        if ($errorType instanceof MissingRouteException) {
           // do something
        }
    }
}
```